# How to customize ExpandedControllerActivity in CastSDK v3

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I would like to customize ExpandedControllerActivity in CastSDK v3 with our own UI. But right now its not permitted. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way or workaround to do this. Upon checking the web, any tutorials and Google documents just shows how to implement or call `ExtendedControllerActivity` and not how to customize the UI in the `ExtendedControllerActivity`. You can try and follow these tutorials for the implementation of `ExtendedControllerActivity`- [Google Cast v3 and Media](http://thebot.net/threads/google-play-services-google-cast-v3-and-media.378577/) and [Expanded Controller](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#9). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the customization is limited to the selection of control buttons that are present on that activity. We, however, are actively looking into expanding on that to add more capabilities; stay tuned.

Comment: 2 years later, there are any news about that?

Comment: 6 years later, there are any news about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize this activity, it's gonna be a lot of work but it is possible. You can create your own layout file with the Views you want and then bind eachView to the informations present in the cast session using [UIMediaController](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/uicontroller/UIMediaController).

There is a lot of possible binding on this UIController so I suggest you try some until your find the one interesting you, here are some exemples :

```
val uiController = UIMediaController(this)
uiController.bindSeekBar(castSeekBar, 1000L) // Binding a CastSeekBar to video progress
uiController.bindTextViewToStreamPosition(castPositionTextView, true) // Binding a TextView to video current position
uiController.bindTextViewToStreamDuration(castDurationTextView) // Binding a TextView to video duration
```

Some of the informations, especially metada fields can be accesed using keys presents in MediaMetadata like title or subtitle :

```
uiController.bindTextViewToMetadataOfCurrentItem(castTitleTextView, MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE)
uiController.bindTextViewToMetadataOfCurrentItem(castSubtitleTextView, MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE)
```

In that activity you can also directly access your video that way :

```
val sessionManager = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this).sessionManager
val remoteMediaClient = sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient
val mediaInfo = remoteMediaClient?.mediaInfo
```

And here, mediaInfo will contains a lot of information like duration, metadata, contentId...

I know it's not very precise but I hope that helps :-)